# How can two urls with single dispatcher servlet and servlet config be mapped to different packages and a package should allow only one URL out of two?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, controller, dispatcher

I have an application where I am using two urls mapped to single Dispatcher servlet.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Default Webservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value> 
                /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Default Webservice</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/xyz/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml** has component scanners. I want some way so that I can allow url with pattern **/abc/*** to be able to access only specific package, not all the packages which dispatcher servlet is scanning.

PS: I cannot change existing url-mapping or create new dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be happen , because the component scan is run as the spring initialize the dispatcher servlet and your request for url is come after the intialization.So the scanning of package by the spring happen before the request.So you cannot put the condition on the component scanning.

If both the url not to work together(Means at one time only one url are active for request).Then can see the use of

1. @Conditional annotation
2. @Profile annotation

Comment: Thanks for answer Ashwani. I will try using these annotations. I think there's no other way than filtering request on controller level.

Comment: yeah, for filtering the request before controller level, you can go for the Spring Security.If I am correctly guessing you need